# How to add command developed with C# to ArcToolbox?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arctoolbox

I have a command that I developed with c#.

I want to add this command to the ArcToolbox.

Is there any way to add such a command to ArcToolbox in ArcGIS Desktop programmatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not develop in C# or C++ but am wondering whether the help page on [Calling a DLL from a script tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001500000013000000) may provide you with a way forward.

Answer (score 3):

The other option is to implement the `IGPFunction2` and `IGPFunctionFactory` interfaces and register them with COM as described in the ArcObjects SDK help: [Custom geoprocessing function tools](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000mrs000000)